# Question about IC regulators

Tags: integrated-circuit

I have a basic question about IC regulators that I know someone here can answer. Basically if I had an IC 7812 regulator in a circuit that has an input voltage of 14 volts, would the output voltage be 12 volts or 26?

Comment: With +14V input, the output will be somewhere around +11.5V, and it will be unstable.  You wonder why?  You can find that out in the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00000444.pdf) (along with a lot of other useful trivia).

Comment: -1 for not reading the datasheet in the first place.  Datasheet is required reading.  Datasheets are readily available free of charge.  So, there is not excuse for not reading it.

Comment: Somewhere between about 11V and 12.5V.

Comment: insufficient preliminary research

Comment: Why would you think that 26V is even a possibility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's no way the output would be 26V, but the older linear regulators like the 7812 required a minimum 2V of headroom (depending on manufacturer) so 14V is right on the edge of regulation.  Still, the output voltage could nominally be 12V for a 14V input, but practically you would want more like 15V input.